# Android Inapp Purchase

Tags: android

I integrated inapp purchase in my app.its working properly on android.test.purchaseId.I uploaded apk in beta testing in play store after that inapp purchase not working on real purchase id i am getting the error message "Failed to signature for sku tirumeni_s01".

Thanks & Regards,
Gowtham.R

Comment: Have you added "tirumeni_s01" to In App product section of Google Play Console?

Comment: Yes i added. Purchased successfully but i am getting this message "Failed to signature for sku tirumeni_s01".